# SQL - select subset of IDs where sum(A) <= X and sum(B) is biggest

Tags: sql, postgresql, subset, self-join

I have table1:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
    itemID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,  
    cost INTEGER NOT NULL,
    income INTEGER NOT NULL  
);
```

I have `MYMONEY` amount of money.

I want SQL to give me the best combination of items which I can buy and sell later to get the biggest income (I sell the items after I leave the shop)

In other words:
Get the subset from `table1` where sum of `cost` in this subset is less or equal to `MYMONEY` and the sum of `income` is highest.

For instance, if we have a table with tuples `(1, 5, 10)`, `(2, 3, 6)`, `(3, 2, 5)` and `MYMONEY=5`  subsets where the first condition is met are `{(1, 5, 10)}` and `{(2, 3, 6), (3, 2, 5)}`. The second condition says that the second subset is better, since sum of `income` in this subset is 11, where in the first subset sum of `income` is 10.

The point is, that those subsets may have various power. If I had a limit of subset's power, I could easily do it by joining or cross-producting the table enough times and choosing the best row.
I could use a counter `c` which says "now let's see only those subsets which power is equal to `c`" and use the solution with cross-product, but I find it slow and ugly.

In case there are many "best" subsets it may just give any of them or all, it is of no importance.

If it matters, I am using PostgreSQL and Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [the Knapsack algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). It's difficult to solve it in sql, so I advice you to get all needed data on client and calc then.

Answer (score 2):

This *can* be done using SQL:

```
with recursive calc as (
   select itemid as itemid, array[itemid] as id_list, cost, income
   from table1
   where cost <= 5
   union all
   select c.itemid, p.id_list||c.itemid, c.cost + p.cost, c.income + p.income
   from table1 as c
     join calc as p on p.itemid < c.itemid
   where c.cost + p.cost <= 5
)
select *
from calc
order by income desc;
```

But just becaus it *can* be done, doesn't necessarily mean it's a good idea to do it.
This query will have a ***horrible*** performance with any real-world table.

Here is a SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/10455/1

Comment: Your solution is full search of all possible combinations. It has terrible complexity. So, I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: @Backs: that's why I said "*will have a horrible performance*".

Comment: if solution has "a horrible performance", is it a solution? ) ok, formaly, it can be solved in sql )